# C: is it possible to associate a pointer to a structure member?

Tags: c, struct, mapping

I want to create something like a mapping array for easy future development of some module. The idea is to have a string that is executed by an external function which always returns a string, that result needs parsing to the right format and then store that in a specific member of a structure(). It would be easy to do this with specific functions but I would like to use a bit more generic approach and functions for this like atoi(or a recreated version of it) if even possible for portability and implementing things quickly in the future.
I created the below structure to hold such a mapping data:

```
typedef struct sMapping
{
    const char *string;
    int (* function)();
    void *storage;
} tMapping;
```

Then created such an array mapping something to the first 2 values:

```
tMapping mapTest[]={
    { .string = "name", .function = te_strcpy},
    { .string = "age", .function = te_atoi},
    { .string = "location", .function = te_parse},
    { .string = "height", .function = te_atoi}
};
```

What I want to have in the code is something like this in the main:

```
char *outputstr = NULL;
for(i = 0; i<MAX_LEAFS; i++)
{
    if(mapTest[i].string == NULL)
        break;

    outputstr = fct_lookup_option_string(mapTest[i].string);
    mapTest[i].function(outputstr);
}
```

So far it all works ok everything is parsed wonderfully. Note that there are 2 variables extracted by the te_atoi function.

Now if I have another struct like

```
typedef struct sSave
{
    char* name;
    int age;
    struct geo *location;
    int height;
} tSave;

tSave person;
```

and want to map something to it

```
(CODE BELOW IS NOT CORRECT, I KNOW, JUST WANT TO PRESENT MY IDEA BETTER)
tMapping mapTest[]={
    { .string = "name", .function = te_strcpy, .storage= &(person.name)}, 
    { .string = "age", .function = te_atoi, .storage= &(person.age)},
    { .string = "location", .function = te_parse, .storage= &(person.location)},
    { .string = "heigth", .function = te_atoi, .storage= &(person.height)},
};
```

to use something like

```
(CODE BELOW IS NOT CORRECT, I KNOW, JUST WANT TO PRESENT MY IDEA BETTER)
mapTest[i].storage = mapTest[i].function(outputstr);
```

is it even possible? Any ideas? Double pointers? C++? Magic? Black Magic?

Thanks.

Please remember that I would like to use this as a generic template for more then one module(and possibly even some automation), so specific functions would limit this a bit more.

Comment: .`storage = &person[i]` doesn't this serve your purpose. Passing the address of the structure to the void pointer? And have `tsave person[num];` array

Comment: That would mean I need to have specific functions for age and heigth wouldn't it? I was thinking maybe there is a way to avoid this and use the same function for all integers just know where to put the result for each?!

Comment: A function for what? If you are trying to update the values in a single API then this assignment should be good enough as you have the address of the structure ..

Comment: I must apologize I have made some corrections to what I wrote first. What I meant to say was age and heigth use the same function te_atoi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting project. It must be motivating to work on it.

Your idea seems good, there's no need C++ but black magic may help :-).

To be serious: yes, it is possible to associate a pointer to a struct member. For char, short, int and long, the way you do it is ok I think.

For strings and structs the parser have to allocate memory. For strings, replacing te_strcpy by te_strdup should do it.

For structs it is a bit more complicated: you have to tell the parser the size of the struct for memory allocation and describe the content of the structure in order to fill it correctly.
In order to do that, one solution may be to add these informations in the tMapping struct :

```
typedef struct sMapping
{
    const char *string;
    int (*function)(char*, void*);
    void *functionParam; // for a te_parse function this param could be a struct containing a tMapping array and a target struct to fill
    void *storage;
} tMapping;
```

The mapTest array becomes :

```
tMapping mapTest[]={
    { .string = "name", .function = te_strdup, .storage= &(person.name)}, 
    { .string = "age", .function = te_atoi, .storage= &(person.age)},
    { .string = "location", .function = te_parse, .functionParam=sMapGeo, .storage= &(person.location)},
    { .string = "height", .function = te_atoi, .storage= &(person.height)},
};
```

To have a generic te_parse function, the sMapGeo struct could be:

```
(THIS CODE WON'T WORK AS IS, BUT IT EXPLAINS THE IDEA)
 struct {
    void *structToFill = &saveGeo;
    int structSize = sizeof(saveGeo);
    tMapping mapStruct[] = 
    { .string="city", .function=te_strdup, .storage=&(saveGeo.city)}
    etc.
 } sMapGeo;
```

Then the te_parse function should look like:

```
void *te_parse(char *input, tParseMap *sMap)
{
    applyMapping(sMap->mapStruct); //apply the mapping like the main mapping
    char *mem = malloc(sMap->structSize);
    memcpy(mem, sMap->structToFill, sMap->structSize));
    return mem;
}
```

A last little thing. Since storage is a pointer, don't forget the * to assign a value to what is pointed:

```
*mapTest[i].storage = mapTest[i].function(outputstr, mapTest[i].functionParam);
```

After all that, treating floats, doubles, arrays and even making code compatible with 32 and 64 bits architecture is another story!

Comment: It did work like a charm, thank you. Sad part was that I had to implement it with double pointers due to time constrain and lack of knowledge, but now I came back and ditched those. Thanks a lot for everything!